# How do I implement my own TaS-Lock in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

So for an assignment we need to have the option to either use the C#-Lock or use a self-implemented TaS-Lock. What I've read about TaS-Locks is that it uses 1 atomic step to both read and write a value. It was suggested to us that we use the Interlocked class in C# for this.

So far this is what I've got, but it seems to result in inconsistent answers:

```
public interface Lock
{
    void Lock();
    void Unlock();
}

public class C_Sharp_Lock : Lock
{
    readonly Object myLock = new object();

    public void Lock()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(myLock);
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(myLock);
    }
}

public class Tas_Lock : Lock
{
    int L = 0;

    public void Lock()
    {
        while (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref L, 1)) { };
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref L, 0);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit**: As a response to Kevin:

I've changed it to the following:

```
public class Tas_Lock : Lock
{
    int L = 0;

    public void Lock()
    {
        while (0 == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref L, 1, 0)) { };
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref L, 0);
    }
}
```

However this still returns inconsistent results.

**Edit #2:** Changes to C# lock:

```
public class C_Sharp_Lock : Lock
{
    readonly Object myLock = new object();
    bool lockTaken = false;

    public void Lock()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(myLock, ref lockTaken);
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        if (lockTaken)
            Monitor.Exit(myLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use CompareExchange in `Lock()`, not Exchange. You musn't change the value if the lock is already taken

Comment: Is this a college assignment or from a course you are doing? I am curious :)

Comment: @vtortola It's part of a college assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the way `Interlocked.CompareExchange` works. It swaps atomatically a value if it's previously equal to the provided comparand, **and returns the previous value**.

In short, `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref L, 1, 0)` will:

- Check whether L is equal to 0
- If L is equal to 0, then it will set L to 1 and return the previous value (0)
- If L isn't equal to 0 (and therefore is equal to 1), then it will return the previous value (1)

From there, what you should do is loop *until* `Interlocked.CompareExchange` returns 0 (which means that the lock was acquired). In your code, you're waiting *while* `Interlocked.CompareExchange` returns 0.

The fixed code:

```
public class Tas_Lock
{
    int L = 0;

    public void Lock()
    {
        while (0 != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref L, 1, 0)) { }
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref L, 0);
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

- The `Interlocked.Exchange` in `Unlock` could be replaced by a faster `Volatile.Write` (or even, though arguable, a simple write)
- If it wasn't for an assignment, you could use the built-in class `SpinLock`, which already does all that stuff in an optimized way

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This has fixed it. I realise now how I should have used it.

Comment: I have another question. My implementation of the standard c# lock sometimes returns an exception because the monitor.Exit tries to exit when a lock hadn't been taken. To fix this, I added a bool to check whether a lock is taken using the overload of the Monitor.Enter method which sets a bool to true when it's taken. However, I now get an argument exception stating that the parameter needs to be initialised as false. I've edited my post so you can see my changes.

Comment: @Heijmaaans Make sure you set lockTaken back to false at the end of Unlock