# How to switch between build in C# lock and own lock implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Depending on an input variable given to the program via the command prompt, I want to use different locks (for a school exercise on concurrency). I want to switch between the build in C# lock and my own TaS implementation.

TaS implementation taken from "[How do I implement my own TaS-Lock in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871859/how-do-i-implement-my-own-tas-lock-in-c)":

```
public class Tas_Lock
{
    int L = 0;

    public void Lock()
    {
        while (0 != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref L, 1, 0)) { }
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref L, 0);
    }
}
```

The only way I can currently think of of switching between the lock statement and my own lock implementation:

```
object obj = new object();
int counter = 0;
bool useOwnImplementation = true; //or false depending on input
Tas_Lock ownLock = new Tas_Lock();

//multiple threads that run simultaneously and call incrementGlobalCounter

incrementGlobalCounter() {
  if (useOwnImplementation) {
    ownLock.Lock();
    counter++;
    ownLock.Unlock();
  } else {
    lock (obj) {
         counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

**I'm wondering if the built in lock statement can use own implementations of locks, or other ways of doing this,** because I don't think this is the right way. Another thing I thought of was rewriting the way C#'s build in lock was implemented in a class, and letting that class and my Tas_Lock class inherit the same Interface (ILock) and then initialize an ILock variable as one of both classes (like in the question supplied). My concerns with this approach are that the exercise says to use the build in lock statement and it also seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You cannot change the code emitted by the `lock` statement, so you really have no other choice than writing your own abstraction on top of it

Comment: Seems like a job for preprocessor macros. If you implement IDisposable in your class you could use a `using` statrment.